# Webhook from Azure Devops to Teams get response 400, bad request

Tags: azure-devops, webhooks, microsoft-teams

I have been fighting and searching about this for 2 days now and I simply cannot find a solution.

As described on the title I am trying to create custom hooks so I can send the desired information.

I know that Teams provides an Azure Devops connector but that is unable to see tenants different than the one the account is connected to. For reasons, that are not important right now, the Azure Devops AD is different from the Teams one and that makes the connector useless.

As such I had to turn to webhooks only to hit another wall.

Any possible solutions would be most welcomed.

Comment: Could you please tell us what you trying to achieve with custom webhooks?

Comment: I want to create multiple hooks so I can send information to the team's, Teams channels. What information... well a lot. Work item comments/updates, PR creations, Pipeline completions, possibly more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to official documentation, just TFS support Web hooks to Teams, but azure devops not.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/services/teams?view=azure-devops

And as my test, if I change the organization to a different AAD, the organization can’t display in teams, I think this is a missing feature. So I have created a feature request about it, you can vote on it and follow the updates.https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/751243/teams-app-connectors-for-azure-devops.html

In addition, according to Microsoft Teams with Azure DevOps Services documentation, only Azure DevOps organization in the same organization(AAD tenant) can be used to integrate with your Microsoft Teams account. You can change your Teams settings to make the AAD tenant is same as your Microsoft Teams account.

Comment: Thanks for the information. The first link does not provide any real information concerning Webhooks other than the fact that the TFS connector is creating one. So I am not sure how you found that Devops in not supporting them. Also the AAD limitation is mentioned there. That is fine. What I find ridiculous in all of this is that Teams cannot handle Devops Webhooks. I do not mind limiting me to only "text" data type but because of an extra depth level (message or detailedMessage) in the JSON, Teams blows up.